# If value within Json is equal to set value then return Name [PHP]

Tags: php, json

So I have a web JSON API and I want to display certain objects from it on my site. Here's my JSON;

```
{
  "descriptions": [
    {
     "name" = "Jim",
     "class" = "3'
    },
    {
     "name" = "luke",
     "class" = "2"
    },
    {
     "name" = "Mat",
     "class" = "3"
    }
```

I would like to make a list of the students in class 3. Currently, this is what I have to gather and pass the data although I'm not sure how to run the check to see if they're in the class and if so return there name.

```
$api = "https://students.com";
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents($api ), true);
$students= $json ["descriptions"][0]["class"];
```

Although that just returns `3` the first class value.

**Note**
*I apologize if there's a similar post but I was unable to find one that answers my simple request. Possibly I'm just not looking in the right place. Thanks in advance*

Comment: you json is not valid json,  `name` should be `"name"`, etc.   You can **[test it out here](https://jsonlint.com)** until is is cleaned up, then your code should work.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Yea sorry, that was just a quick example I made xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()` also.

`$filteredStudent = array_filter($json["description"], function($value) {
    return $value["class"] == 3;
});`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: How would I actually put this into practice? I strangely wasn't able to use the code you posted... I'm not sure if it means anything but my Json Request includes `[0]` and it doesn't appear to work due to that, when I put it into the array it broke... Possibly I'm doing something wrong :p

Comment: @CharlieSimon in case if any exceptions have been occurred. You should check all of them before using this function

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($json["descriptions"] as $value)
{
    if($value['class'] == '3')
        $names[] = $value['name'];
}
return $names;
```